# can we automatically create a list from a previously created list template?

Tags: list, flow, list-template

I have saved a **list template** in list template gallery. I want to use **Microsoft Flow** to create a **list** from the **template**. Is this possible?

Otherwise, can I customize the list during creation in Flow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can create list using custom template in MS Flow, for that we need use the "Send an http request to SharePoint "  action of MS Flow...

For detailed implementation please refer the below thread :

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-Custom-List-using-list-template/td-p/237100

https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/08/28/sharepoint-microsoft-flow-maintain-list-details-for-no-code-developers/

**Update** :

The above exercise will create a generic list (template I'd 100) but not list from the custom list stored in list template gallery.... for this possible work around would be:

Need to create a Azure function and call it from flow and use powershell to create the library from a template.

**Explanation about Azure function approach** :

We know that we can create list from the custom list template using the PowerShell coding.... this is the key point for this approach.

Create a custom list name as "auto list creation set up" create three columns:

- List Title - text type
- List Description - multi text
- List template selection - choice ddl with the value of your "custom list template name"

  Now create a MS Flow on this list with the action when an item is created put a message on Azure queue.

Now create a Azure function using PS script or c# which will be triggered whenever any message comes to the Azure queue.... read all input from here and write your code to create the list based on your custom template.

The below reference example explains how site can be created using the Azure function... the same logic we can use for list creation.

**Reference URL :**

https://www.sharepointfire.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-pnp-site-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-function/?cn-reloaded=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I create a list based on a template in the template gallery? In the HTTP request the template used is BaseTemplate:100, how can I use my own?

Comment: Yes, you are right.... updated the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain the method explicitly ? I would be grateful if you could.

Comment: @bAbdenour: Added the approach details in the answer section... please refer the updated answer.